# Rotate ImageView and FrameLayout correctly

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, android-framelayout, image-rotation

I have an Imageview inside a **FrameLayout** (both have **Layout_margins**),also i got my custom FrameLayout(same with **Layout_margins**).
So what i have now:
[image: Source]
Source code(.axml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffff363c"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:clickable="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="80">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/SourceFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Img"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <CustomFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/CustomView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And what i want exactly(programmatically rotation left,right via button):
[image: MyGoal]

So my main goal is to rotate properly image(and CustomFrameLayout too),also i need to store my source Width/Height of image.How can i achieve this?
I tried to set scaleType.center / scaletype.centerInisde , but that is wrong idea.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if i exactly understand your problem.
If u want programmatically rotate something u can try this:

```
ImageView image.animate().rotation(90).start();
```

or this

```
FrameLayout frame.animate().rotation(90).start();
```

or both.
To store Width/Height u can use

```
int image_h = image.getHeight();
int image_w = image.getWidth();
```

Comment: my question is: how to rotate image like i showed (see images). To put imageView and MyCustomFrameLayout in these borders(see image 2).

Comment: add this:
 <ImageView
...
android:scaleType="centerInside"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
...
/>
...
<CustomFrameLayout
...
android:layout_gravity="center"
...
          />
and this:
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
Img.animate().rotation(90).start();
CustomView.animate().rotation(90).start();
});

//this may work well for the image. Don't know how to deal with the CustomFrameLayout since there is no image inside. I'd work with only one FrameLayout, but surely you have good reasons to use them.

Comment: thanks for the reply,but i need to know what parameters i need to use(centerinsde/center and etc). That is not simple rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

I was facing the exactly same problem.
After some trying, I came with this solution:

```
private void rotateImageBy90(){
    imageView.animate()
            .rotation(90)
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
            .setDuration(250)
            .setListener(rotateListener)
            .start();
    Log.d("chatImage", "Rotating image by "+90+" degrees clockwise");
}
```

Declare an AnimatorListener, the one that solves the problem:

```
Animator.AnimatorListener rotateListener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.requestLayout();

        //This is the trick: I get the current bitmap, rotate it 
        Bitmap newBitmap = rotateImage(((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(),90);
        //Then, rotate the imageview back to it's original position, without animation
        imageView.setRotation(0);
        //As I set the new, rotate bitmap, to it.
        imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

    }
};
```

The rotateImage method:

```
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix,
            true);
}
```